# How to perform a for comprehension on Either return types that are wrapped in a F

Tags: scala, scala-cats

Is there an easier way to flatMap over s1,s2,s3 such that I don't have to perform a match in my yield clause?

```
 serviceFoo1(): F[Either[String, Foo]]
 serviceFoo2(): F[Either[String, Foo]]
 serviceFoo3(): F[Either[String, Foo]]

 for {
     s1 <- serviceFoo1()
     s2 <- serviceFoo2()
     s3 <- serviceFoo3()
 } yield {
     (s1, s2, s3) match  {
         case (Right(a), Right(b), Right(c)) => MyFooWrapper(a,b,c).some
         case _ => None
     }
 }
```

From what I know .flatMap on an Either will continue only when it is a `Right`, but since my response is wrappedin a `F` I am hoping there is some elegant way to handle this...

Comment: `(EitherT(serviceFoo1()), EitherT(serviceFoo2()), EitherT(serviceFoo3()).mapN(MyFooWrapper.apply).map(_.map(_.right.toOption))`

Comment: Look at Cat's `EitherT`: https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/eithert.html